# MySQL - Select Records that matches all values

Tags: mysql, join, select, relational-division

If a table "XYZ" contains two columns as combine primary key, I need to select records that contain both Value1 `and` Value2 in COLUMN_B ( Result: ID4 )

I tried with "IN" query `select COLUMN_A from XYZ where COLUMN_B in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2');`  but it returns the records which contain VALUE1 `OR` VALUE2 in COLUMN_B (ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4).

Can anybody please help me to write a MySQL query that can do this.

```
COLUMN_A    COLUMN_B

ID1         Value1
ID2         Value1
ID3         Value2
ID4         Value1
ID4         Value2
ID5         Value3
ID3         Value3
```

Comment: Your query contains a join, post the query and the related tables

Answer (score 4):

This is a messy way of doing it on a very large table, but it will accomplish the goal:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A
  FROM xyz
 WHERE COLUMN_B IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
 GROUP BY COLUMN_A
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_B) = 2;
```

This counts the number of distinct `COLUMN_B` values for each `COLUMN_A` record and returns only the records that have both `Value1` and `Value2`. Note that this will not exclude `COLUMN_A` records that have additional values, such as `Value3` and `Value4`. That would require a different sort of query that would need to take the size of the source table into consideration ...

Comment: If the current `PRIMARY KEY` is `(col_a, col_b)`, then add `INDEX(col_b, col_a)`.

Comment: perfect useful query

Answer (score 1):

I should test this first before suggesting, but what about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableA.column_A  
FROM XYZ AS tableA, XYZ AS tableB
WHERE tableA.column_A = tableB.column_A
    AND tableA.column_B = 'Value1'
    AND tableB.column_B = 'Value2'
```